# A term that is not bounded by 1.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequence-of-function

$f_{n}(x)= \frac{n^3 x^{3/2}}{ 1 + n^4 x^2}\}$ I think when $0 < x <1$ this expression is bounded by 1, am I correct? if so how can I prove it?

**My trials:**

At $x = 1,$ the following fraction $\{ \frac{n^3 x^{3/2}}{ 1 + n^4 x^2}\}$ becomes  $\{\frac{n^3 }{ 1 + n^4}\}$ which is clearly less than 1 as  $n^3 < 1 + n^4$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}.$\

At $x = 0,$ the following fraction $\{ \frac{n^3 x^{3/2}}{ 1 + n^4 x^2}\}$ becomes $0$ which is less than 1.\

At $0 < x < 1,$ we have  $x < 1,$ then  $x^{3/2} < 1.$, so $n^3 x^{3/2} < n^3 < n^4 + 1.$ OTOH, $x^2 < 1$, then $1 + n^4 x^2 < 1 +  n^4$ and so $\frac {1}{1 +  n^4 x^2} > \frac{1}{ 1 +  n^4}$, So it seems like in this case this term is not bounded by 1.

**{A counterexample:}**

if $n^{3}x^{3/2} \leq C (1+n^{4}x^{2})$ for all $n$ and for all $x$ then we can put $x =\frac 1 {n^{2}}$ to get $1 \leq 2C$ which is true. I am confused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you differentiate $f_n$ for $n \geq 1$ you have that the function attains its maximum at $x=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{n^2}$ on $[0,1]$

Comment: what about $n =1$?

Comment: Do the same procedure for $n=1,2$ and then take the maximum of bounds.

Comment: In your answer, you said: "for n > 2 you have ....", I have differentiated the function and I can see that this condition (n > 2) is not necessary as in $f(\sqrt{3}/n)$ the $n's$ are canceled.

Comment: am I correct or no ?

Comment: @Secretly the $n's$ are not canceled  if you plug in $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{n}$  since in the denominator you have  $n^4x^2$

Comment: I am sorry it is $\sqrt {3} / n^2$ ... it was typo

Comment: For $n=1$ again $f_1$ is bounded by $1$...i just took $n>2$ for easier calculation when taking the derivative of $f_n$...thus again you have the conclusion

Comment: If you differentiate then then the points you mention are the maximums of $f_n$

Comment: How the calculations will be easier .... could you give me a hint please?

Comment: @Secretly you are right..we do not need $n>2$ althoug it does not matter..i edited my answer.